# mouse (not keyboard) sharing with barrier between Ubuntu and windows

Tags: mouse, sharing

I'm using barrier to share mouse and keyboard between several machines with Ubuntu and windows os.
I'm looking for a possibility to share the mouse only, but not the keyboard. Is this possible with barrier or is there any other software providing this option?